# How to safely stop watchdog observer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, watchdog, python-watchdog

I am trying to find a way to safely stop my running watchdog event handler.
My function is getting a command parameter, if a command is to stop watchdog event observer, then it should stop the event and listener as long as it completes its task safely which means that I do not want to interrupt the task.

I would appreciate if you provide supports on that issue.

Thank you.

**UPDATE:1**

I tried to follow library documentation, my implementation was like below:

```
observer.schedule(event_handler, this_cfg.inbound_folder_path)
observer.start()
print('Listening {} folder..........'.format(this_cfg.inbound_folder_path))
try:
   while True:           
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
observer.join()
```

After that I found an attribute in observer class, and changed the implementation as below:

```
 observer.schedule(event_handler, this_cfg.inbound_folder_path)
 observer.start()
 print('Listening {} folder..........'.format(this_cfg.inbound_folder_path))
 try:
    while (observer.event_queue.unfinished_tasks != 0 and stop_signal!=True):
      time.sleep(1)
    observer.stop()
    observer.join()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
```

What do you think about my approach? I would appreciate if you know a better solution. Thank you

Comment: Could you please provide some code, and maybe a bit of context too. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. I tried to provide some implementations. It is also showing my latest status for the idea.

Comment: Thank you for updating your code that is very helpful!

Comment: no problem. I hope someone may have better idea